# How do i fix: Run time error '404' Object required

Tags: vba, ms-word

Clicking on Form button should generate random array with 10 numbers, and sort it by calling module 'SortMas'

```
   Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim i As Integer, b(10) As Single
    Dim CurRange As Range
    ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Add
ActiveDocument.Content.InsertAfter Text:="Random array:"
ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Add
    For i = 1 To 10
        b(i) = Int(10 * Rnd + 10)
        ActiveDocument.Content.InsertAfter Text:=Str(b(i)) + " "
    Next i
    
ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Add

 Text:="Sorted array: "
Call SortMas(b(), 10, 2)
ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Add
For i = 1 To 10
ActiveDocument.Content.InsertAfter Text:=Str(b(i)) + " "
Next i
End Sub
```

Error on 4th line:
ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Add

Error msg is on fourth line of code:
[image: Error msg]

Comment: add option explicit at the top to see non declared vars. I think you need to reference Application.ActiveDocument

Comment: You're getting that particular specific error because `ActiveDocument` is undefined in an Excel project, because `Option Explicit` isn't specified at the top of the module, so the code is allowed to run with late-bound implicit `Variant/Empty` variables instead. With `Option Explicit`, the compiler would be complaining about `ActiveDocument` being an undeclared variable. Any late-bound member call against `Variant/Empty` will throw error 424 "object required", because member calls are only valid against an object reference.

Answer (score 1):

The code is working for me in the MS word.
Are you using excel or word?.
In Excel it will throw error 424 as paragraph is not  part of excel, But it works good in Word. open Word---> Atl + F11 ---> Insert a module---> put the code it is working

```
  Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim i As Integer, b(10) As Single
    Dim CurRange As Range
    
'For i2 = 1 To 100
    ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Add
ActiveDocument.Content.InsertAfter Text:="Random array:"

ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Add
    For i = 1 To 10
        b(i) = Int(10 * Rnd + 10)
        ActiveDocument.Content.InsertAfter Text:=Str(b(i)) + " "
    Next i
    
ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Add

 ActiveDocument.Content.InsertAfter Text:="Sorted array: "
'Call SortMas(b(), 10, 2)
ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Add
For i = 1 To 10
ActiveDocument.Content.InsertAfter Text:=Str(b(i)) + " "
Next i

'Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You were right, i did it in microsoft excel. Thank you!